# Using ggsignif with grouped bar graphs and facet_wrap not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `ggsignif` for displaying significant stars in top of paired bar graphs using facet_wrap. However, I can´t manage to find a way of displaying one significant bar per facet. Here is what I mean:

```
    dat <- data.frame(Group = c("S1", "S1", "S2", "S2"),
                  Sub   = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
                  Value = c(3,5,7,8))

    ggplot(dat, aes(Group, Value)) +
      geom_bar(aes(fill = Sub), stat="identity", position="dodge", width=.5) +
      geom_signif(y_position=c(5.3, 8.3), xmin=c(0.8, 1.8), xmax=c(1.2, 2.2),
              annotation=c("**", "NS"), tip_length=0) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey80", "grey20")) +
      facet_grid(~ Group, scales = "free")
```

[image: output]

Is there a way of making sure that each facet has its individual significance label?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem seems to me is that the geom_signif layer doesn't know to what panel the variables go to, since it has no `data` argument provided.

I'm not that familiar with the package, but the documentation seems to suggest that `manual = TRUE` is recommended for plotting it in different facets. Doing that and making some adjustments for the errors that were thrown, I got the following to work:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Group, Value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Sub), stat="identity", position="dodge", width=.5) +
  geom_signif(data = data.frame(Group = c("S1","S2")),
              aes(y_position=c(5.3, 8.3), xmin=c(0.8, 0.8), xmax=c(1.2, 1.2),
              annotations=c("**", "NS")), tip_length=0, manual = T) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey80", "grey20")) +
  facet_grid(~ Group, scales = "free")
```

[image]

The key seemed to be to provide a `data` argument from which the facetting code could deduce what bit goes in what panel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using ggpubr and `stat_compare_means`?
https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/stat_compare_means.html

Since your example only contains one observation pr. bar it does not work but if you include multiple observations you can get what you want.

rewrite the test data:

```
dat <- data.frame(A_S1 = sample(rnorm(20, 3, 1)),
              B_S1 = sample(rnorm(20, 5, 1)),
              A_S2 = sample(rnorm(20, 7, 1)),
              B_S2 = sample(rnorm(20, 8, 1))) %>% 
tidyr::gather("G", "value") %>% 
tidyr::separate("G", c("Sub", "Group"))
```

Plot the data using the ggpubr package

```
ggerrorplot(dat, x = "Sub", y = "value",
            facet.by = "Group",
            error.plot = "pointrange") +
stat_compare_means(aes(label = ..p.signif..),
                   method = "t.test", ref.group = "A")
```

[image]