# How to define data when using ggsignif with grouped bar graphs and facet_wrap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

EDITED

I was using the ggsignif package in a totally WRONG way: I didn't want to calculate significance values from the barplot but I just wanted to draw on the barplot the ones I already had from a separate analysis. To do this, this video helped me A LOT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30mqU2vcx68

OLD QUESTION

Hello, I'd like to ask a question about the ggsignif package in the R software. I want to display significant stars in top of paired bar graphs using facet_wrap and I'm following this thread [Using ggsignif with grouped bar graphs and facet_wrap not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219468/using-ggsignif-with-grouped-bar-graphs-and-facet-wrap-not-working) but I cannot apply the same code to my graph. As in the image I attach, I'd like to make comparisons between bars as I drew, but I don't know how to define the data I'm comparing.

I used this code to build my graph:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c("S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2"),
                  Sub   = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B","B"),
                  col = c("red", "green", "red", "green","red", "green", "red", "green"),
                  Value = c(10,6,10,7,9,5,9,8)) 


ggplot(df, aes(x=Group, y=Value, fill=col)) + 
  scale_fill_manual("col", values = c("red" = "red", "green" = "green")) +
  facet_wrap(~Sub)  + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,15)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

Do you know how I can define the coordinates for significance stars in a plot similar to this one? Thank you very very much![image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Significance refers to a distribution requiring many values per group. But for each group (e.g. S1-green-A) there is only one value in your dataset. Thus you draw a barplot and not a boxplot. You can group more values together e.g. by ignoring the color:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Group = c("S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2"),
  Sub = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
  col = c("red", "green", "red", "green", "red", "green", "red", "green"),
  Value = c(10, 6, 10, 7, 9, 5, 9, 8)
)

df %>%
  unite(Group2, Group, Sub) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Group2, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggsignif::geom_signif(
    comparisons = list(
      c("S1_A", "S1_B"),
      c("S1_A", "S2_A")
    ),
    step_increase = 0.2
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @danloo! You made me realize that I was using ggsignif in a totally WRONG way... I didn't want to calculate significance values but I just wanted to draw on the plot the ones I got in separate analyses. For doing this, this video helped me a lot [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30mqU2vcx68)