# Use ggsignif to put significance bars over facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do almost [exactly this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219468/using-ggsignif-with-grouped-bar-graphs-and-facet-wrap-not-working).   I have this graph:

[image]

From this data frame:

```
Data<-structure(list(Op = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes"), Drug = c("No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes"), Follow = c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", 
"Yes"), n = c(46, 101, 25, 27, 2, 65, 2, 22), Percent = c(31.29251701, 
68.70748299, 48.07692308, 51.92307692, 2.985074627, 97.01492537, 
8.333333333, 91.66666667)), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    Op = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector"
    )), Drug = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Follow = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), n = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Percent = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x000001fa6e358930>, row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And the graph was made with this code:

```
Data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Drug,
             y = Percent, 
             fill = Follow)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2") +
  labs(x = "", 
       fill = "Follow", 
       title = "Drug vs Follow") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("n=",n)), 
            vjust = -0.2, 
            position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_grid(.~Op) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0("n=",n)), 
            vjust = -0.2, 
            position = position_dodge(.9))
```

I'd love to manually draw in significance bars that look like this:

[image]

But I am having trouble following the code in that linked answer.  When I add:

```
geom_signif(data = data.frame(Op = c("No","Yes")),
            aes(y_position=c(5.3, 8.3), 
                xmin=c(0.8, 0.8), 
                xmax=c(1.2, 1.2),
                annotations=c("**", "NS")), 
            tip_length=0, 
            manual = T)
```

to the end of my code, I get the error *' "Follow" not found '*.  (P.s. I'm sure the numbers were wrong and in wrong position, I was just hoping to get some bars and then I'd move them around)

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `geom_signif` inherits the global aesthetics you set inside `ggplot()`. In particular, as you set `fill=Follow` ggplot is expecting a variable with this name in the dataframe you passed via the `data` argument of `geom_signif`.

One option to solve this issue would be to make `fill=Follow` a local aesthetic to `geom_col` which also requires to map `Follow` on the group `aes` inside `geom_text`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Drug, y = Percent)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Follow), position = "dodge2") +
  labs(x = "", fill = "Follow", title = "Drug vs Follow") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("n=", n), group = Follow), vjust = -0.2, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Op) +
  geom_signif(data = data.frame(Op = c("No", "Yes")), aes(y_position = c(5.3, 8.3), xmin = c(0.8, 0.8), xmax = c(1.2, 1.2), annotations = c("**", "NS")), tip_length = 0, manual = T)
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: y_position, xmin, xmax, annotations
```

A second option would be to set `inherit.aes=FALSE` in `geom_signif`.

```r
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Drug, y = Percent, fill = Follow)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2") +
  labs(x = "", fill = "Follow", title = "Drug vs Follow") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("n=", n)), vjust = -0.2, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Op) +
  geom_signif(data = data.frame(Op = c("No", "Yes")), 
    aes(y_position = c(5.3, 8.3), xmin = c(0.8, 0.8), xmax = c(1.2, 1.2),
        annotations = c("**", "NS")), tip_length = 0, manual = T,
        inherit.aes = FALSE)
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: y_position, xmin, xmax, annotations
```

[image]